# How to preload assets from one scene to another in Phaser

Tags: reactjs, phaser-framework

I am initializing my phaser game in react

```
export const initPhaser = async () => {
  const [Bootstrap, GameScene, InteriorScene, Phaser] = await Promise.all([
    import('@/scenes/Bootstrap'),
    import('@/scenes/GameScene'),
    import('@/scenes/InteriorScene'),
    import('phaser'),
  ])

  const config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    parent: 'game-content',
    backgroundColor: '#123456',
    pixelArt: true, // Prevent pixel art from becoming blurred when scaled
    scale: {
      mode: Phaser.Scale.ScaleModes.RESIZE,
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    },
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade',
      arcade: {
        gravity: { y: 0 },
      },
    },
    scene: [Bootstrap.default, GameScene.default, InteriorScene.default],
  }

  const phaserGame = new Phaser.Game(config)

  return phaserGame
}
```

I have a Bootstrap class

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export default class Bootstrap extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super('Bootstrap')
  }

  preload() {
    // Load spritesheet and tileset images for Serene Village
    this.load.spritesheet('adam', 'sprites/adam.png', {
      frameWidth: 32,
      frameHeight: 48,
    })
    this.load.image('tiles', 'maps/Serene_Village_48x48_extruded.png')
    this.load.image('collision', 'maps/Collision_48x48.png')
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('tilemap', 'maps/SereneVillage_Demo.json')
  }
}
```

I have a GameScene class I would like to preload assets from Bootstrap

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export default class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super('GameScene')
  }

  preload() {
    // would like like to preload assets from Bootstrap
  }
}
```

What do I have to put in the preload of GameScene to load assets from Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything, just use the same `key` as in the `BootScene`, and you should be able to use it in the `GameScene`.

**Here a short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene { 

    constructor() {
        super('Boot');
    }

    preload(){
      this.load.image('logo', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/phaser2.png');
    }

    create() {
        // do stuff
        this.add.text(10,10, 'Scene Boot ... ')
          .setOrigin(0);       
        this.add.image(40, 40, 'logo')
            .setScale(.36)
            .setOrigin(0);
        setTimeout( () => this.scene.start('Game'), 1000)
    }
}

class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super('Game');
    }

    create() {
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'Game')
            .setOrigin(0)
            
        this.add.image(200, 40, 'logo')
            .setScale(.40)
            .setOrigin(0);
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [BootScene, GameScene]
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```